# Continuous integration servers for .NET applications?

Tags: .net, continuous-integration

Related to [Continuous Integration Servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140453/continuous-integration-servers).

But I'm interested in .NET instead of Java.  I've mostly heard of people using CruiseControl.NET for CI of .NET applications but I've also heard that Hudson is a better CI product.  Has anyone used Hudson for .NET CI?  Can anyone recommend any other CI Servers that work well with .NET?

**UPDATE**

Bonus points for a free CI Server...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hudson has [no problem with .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582687/ci-hudson-with-net-vs-cruisecontrol-net).

Comment: Seconded We use hudson for a .NET project.

Comment: Went with Hudson.  Like it so far!

Answer (score 4):

I can HIGHLY recommend TeamCity! And especially after their newest release 6.0, its amazing how much you can put into one product.

http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/

And its even free for smaller teams up to a certain amounts of configurations.

Answer (score 3):

Team Foundation Server ... the 2010 version has great CI